# How to allocate memory for std::vector and then call constructor for some elements later?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, constructor, stl

I'm "modernizing" a (pretty old) C++ project, and stumbling on this part:

The old code allocates memory for a dynamic array, then call constructor later for element if needed. I guess calling constructor for all elements is expensive, so the author chose to do this way (performance is critical for this project). The old code looks like this (simplified):

```
struct my_struct {
    my_struct(int x, int y, int z) { /* expensive ctor */ }
};

struct other_class {
    my_struct* arr;
    other_class(int n) {        
        arr = (my_struct*) malloc(n * sizeof(arr[0]);
    }

    void foo(int idx, int a, int b, int c) {
        new (&arr[idx]) my_struct(a, b, c);
    }
};
```

I changed `arr` to `std::vector<my_struct>`, and use `std::reserve` to "reserve" the memory. The code works okay, pass all current tests, but I know it's not okay, since `std::reserve` doesn't increase the size of that vector, so calling `arr.size()` will still return 0. Here's my code:

```
struct other_class {
    std::vector<my_struct> arr;
    other_class(int n) {        
        arr.reserve(n);
    }

    void foo(int idx, int a, int b, int c) {
        new (&arr[idx]) my_struct(a, b, c);
    }
};
```

How to make this code fast and safe (assuming that I can't add a default ctor to `my_struct`)? Thank you.

---

Edit: here's the sample code. It is compiled and run as expected, without any warnings: http://cpp.sh/8ytwf

Comment: It doesn't matter how much memory have been allocated for the vector (its *capacity*), as long as the size is zero all indexes will be out of bounds.

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't support having the constructed objects in the vector at arbitrary locations in the vector; the first `size()` elements must all be alive (i.e. must have been contructed), and the remaining elements (up to capacity()) must not be alive (i.e. must not have been constructed/must have been destructed). How did the original code keep track of what was alive and not alive, in order to appropriately call the destructors only on non-alive objects?

Comment: Some options you have are: Use `std::option`. Add a default ctor to `my_struct`. Add a new custom data-structure (operating over raw memory) that contains a list of "live" elements (perhaps as a bit-array) and properly manages the lifetimes.

Comment: Or possibly the code is structured such that by the time that `other_class` is destroyed, `foo` has been called exactly once for every `idx` in [0, n). If so, there would be no need to explicitly track what is and is not alive within the array. This kind of unsafe code should probably tightly limited to a small set of uses.

Answer (score 7):

> but I know it's not okay, since std::reserve doesn't increase the size of that vector

`std::reserve` does increase the vectors capacity and when you only want to allocate memory and only later push elements, then that is exactly what you want.

The size of the underlying array that the vector manages is not equal to the vectors `size()`. `size()` returns the number of elements in the container and as long as there aren't any `size() == 0`.

When you later push elements you need not use placement new, but you should use `push_back` or `emplace_back`. More specifially, this is wrong:

```
 new (&arr[idx]) my_struct(a, b, c);
```

Because you are accessing the vector out-of-bounds (remember: size is number of elements, capacity can be bigger but you cannot access indices bigger than the vectors size). Instead:

```
 arr.emplace_back(a,b,c);
```

Comment: Note that `arr.emplace_back(a,b,c);` doesn't take `idx` into account, while the original code does, so it isn't a direct replacement. You need to make additional adjustments to make the code work with `std::vector`.

Comment: @Mankarse thats correct, but vectors dont have empty slots, they are not sparse. You cannot add an element at index `42` when there are no elements at indices up to `41`. If that is really needed, there are solutions, but I didn't want to put too much into the answer

Comment: I believe this `new (&arr[idx]) my_struct(a, b, c);` is not wrong. My sample code is compiled and run fine: http://cpp.sh/8ytwf 

AFAIK, `vector::[]` operator does not do range-check. Only `vector::at()` does

Comment: @Scorta it is undefined behavior. No doubt. The size is still `0` and you can all sorts of weird effects. Try to copy the vector for example

Comment: @idclev 463035818, ah, yes, that's right. I meant it works as I need, but it's not safe.

Answer (score 2):

Although I like the `emplace_back` solution better, you could use `std::optional` in this case. This would allow you to use the `idx` to determine which element gets populated with a valid object.

```
struct other_class 
{
    std::vector<std::optional<my_struct>> arr;
    other_class( int n ) : arr( n, std::nullopt )
    { }

    void foo( int idx, int a, int b, int c ) 
    {
        arr.at( idx ).emplace( a, b, c );
    }
};
```

Comment: This solution is closest to what I need, but my corp has not adopted C++17, so I cannot use it now :(  --  May I know why you prefer the `emplace_back`? It cannot construct element at random index.

Comment: I prefer the `emplace_back` due to its simplicity. That being said, if you're not using `C++17` you only have a couple of options I can think of. First, use `boost::optional`. If you're already using the `boost` library this is your best option. Second, you could write your own `optional` type.